# Getting WooCommerce Order ID within email template hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Does anyone know how to get an order id for customizing email templates via hooks?

I’m working with a custom API that returns a bill based on order id, and I’m also trying to print it in an email template.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function ( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    echo '<pre>' . FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip( $order->get_id() ) . '</pre>';
}, 10, 4 );
```

In that way, I'm not getting the bill. But if I hardcode the order id, then everything is working.

## EDIT

When I dump the $order I got the complete object:

```
["items":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    ["line_items"]=>
    array(3) {
      [118]=>
      object(WC_Order_Item_Product)#2019 (11) {
        ["extra_data":protected]=>
        array(9) {
          ["product_id"]=>
          int(0)
          ["variation_id"]=>
          int(0)
          ["quantity"]=>
          int(1)
          ["tax_class"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["subtotal"]=>
          int(0)
          ["subtotal_tax"]=>
          int(0)
          ["total"]=>
          int(0)
          ["total_tax"]=>
          int(0)
          ["taxes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["subtotal"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["total"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(11) {
          ["order_id"]=>
          int(55)
          ["name"]=>
          string(9) "Product 1"
          ["product_id"]=>
          int(11)
          ["variation_id"]=>
          int(0)
          ["quantity"]=>
          int(1)
          ["tax_class"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["subtotal"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["subtotal_tax"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["total"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["total_tax"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["taxes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["total"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["subtotal"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
        ["cache_group":protected]=>
        string(11) "order-items"
        ["meta_type":protected]=>
        string(10) "order_item"
        ["object_type":protected]=>
        string(10) "order_item"
        ["id":protected]=>
        int(118)
        ["changes":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["object_read":protected]=>
        bool(true)
        ["default_data":protected]=>
        array(11) {
```

But when I try to access it in the following way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function ( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    echo '<pre>' . FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip( $order[order_id] ) . '</pre>';
}, 10, 4 );
```

I got an Internal Server Error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify what `$order` actually contains at this point?

Comment: @CBroe No. I checked in the documentation here http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.3/actions/woocommerce_email_after_order_table/, and it just said `the order`. Any workaround for this?

Comment: No, you are not able to verify it? Or it doesn't contain anything?

Comment: @CBroe I've just edited my question. Could you please check?

Comment: Anything that says `["...":protected]` in the debug output, is very likely _not_ an array. Is it an actual instance of `WC_Order`? (Debug output should also show you the type, it looks like you cut parts of it off in what you have shown us.)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `echo '<pre>' . FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip( $order->get_id() ) . '</pre>';` with just `echo $order->get_id();`. 
You say if you hardcode the id it works.. but maybe it's an ID of an older order object you use against the current one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function ( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
$order_id = $order_data['id'];
    echo '<pre>' . FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip($order_id ) . '</pre>';
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Echo $order_id,what it returns

Comment: I've just edited my question. Could you please check?

Comment: Try this,  $order->order_id

Answer (score 0):

As CBroe mentioned, verify what order contains.

I remember that when I was working with WooCommerce `$order->get_id()` was the post's id and that I had to use `$order->get_order_number()`

Comment: No. I checked in the documentation here http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.3/actions/woocommerce_email_after_order_table/, and it just said `the order`. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I've just edited my question. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

The API in question probably requires the order number and not the post id. Change

```
 FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip( $order->get_id() )
```

to

```
FS4E_VSDC::fs4e_get_order_slip( $order->get_order_number() )
```